# jQuery/XML return the current target li id from an xml node for individual functions

Tags: jquery

I need to return the current value of the selected video-thumb li, so if I click on the 2nd li return id is 2 etc.  What I currently have returns 2 if I select both the first and second li.  I will eventually need to fire a different function depending on the selected li.  If this is totally off on reaching that goal please point me in the correct lead.

What I am trying to accomplish:  I parse the xml and then display it on the page (append it to #container).  Within the appended html, li are added.  Upon this addition I need to iterate to the correct target li.  So if I click target li with the xml id of 3 I need to fire a function for only that target li and so on for all iterated xml nodes.  Any direct as always is greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

jQuery:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.6.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/video-js/video.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="js/video-js/video-js.css" type="text/css" media="screen" title="Video JS" charset="utf-8">
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "videos.xml",
        dataType: "xml",
        success: function(xml) {
            $(xml).find('videos').each(function(){
                var title = $(this).find('title').text();
                var id = $(this).find('id').text();
                var url = $(this).find('url').text();
                var url2 = $(this).find('url2').text();
                var desc = $(this).find('desc').text();
                //alert(url2);
                $('#container').append('<div id="desc">'+title+'<br>'+desc+'</div><video class="video-js" width="740" height="400" controls="controls" preload="true"><source src="'+url+'"/><source src="'+url2+'"/></video><li class="video-thumb">'+id+'</li>');
                $('.video-thumb').click(function() {
                    if(id == 2){
                    alert("click = " + id);
                    } else {
                        return false
                    alert("loser");   
                    }
                })
            });
        }
    });
    //VideoJS.setupAllWhenReady();

});
```

XML:

```
<xml>
<videos>
  <title>title one</title>
  <id>1</id>
  <url>videos/video1.mp4</url>
  <url2>videos/video1.webm</url2>
  <desc>111 Writing things in here.  Writing things in here.  Writing things in here.</desc>
</videos>
<videos>
  <title>title 2</title>
  <id>2</id>
  <url>videos/video1.mp4</url>
  <url2>videos/video1.webm</url2>
  <desc>2 Writing things in here.  Writing things in here.  Writing things in here.</desc>
</videos>
<videos>
  <title>title 3</title>
  <id>3</id>
  <url>videos/video1.mp4</url>
  <url2>videos/video1.webm</url2>
  <desc>3 Writing things in here.  Writing things in here.  Writing things in here.</desc>
</videos>
<videos>
  <title>title 4</title>
  <id>4</id>
  <url>videos/video1.mp4</url>
  <url2>videos/video1.webm</url2>
  <desc>4 Writing things in here.  Writing things in here.  Writing things in here.</desc>
</videos>
</xml>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're binding a click handler to each list item that is being added. That is fine, but instead you could add only one handler to the outermost element that will catch all clicks, and depending on which `li` was clicked, you can take the appropriate action.

Here's some code to get you started,

```
$(xml).find('videos').each(function() {
    // create HTML and add this video to the page
});

// Add just one click handler to the container node.
$("#container").delegate(".video-thumb", "click", function() {
    // get the id from the text of the li node that was just clicked.
    var id = $(this).text();
});
```